# Can't get HorizontalRangeSlider to render correctly with dojo 1.8

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to get dojo's HorizontalRangeSlider to work, [but a simple example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonbri/g78Uk/) doesn't seem to be rendering correctly (Firefox 16 or Chrome).

Is this the correct component to use for a slider with multiple heads? [The documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/form/RangeSlider.html) for 1.8 is still using 1.6 conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample is missing a stylesheet. The `dojox/form/RangeSlider` ships with one, found under `dojox/form/resources`.

Add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojox/form/resources/RangeSlider.css" 
/>
```

to your html output

See http://jsfiddle.net/g78Uk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of the fiddle with a ruler, added programatically.

```
    var sliderRules = new dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels({
        minimum: 0,
        maximum: 12,
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        labelStyle: "font-size:9px;color: #333",
        style: "width:300px;height:30px;"
    }, "ruler");


    var rangeSlider = new dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider({
        name: "rangeSlider",
        value: [2, 6],
        minimum: 0,
        maximum: 12,
        discreteValues: 12,
        style: "width:300px;",
        onChange: function (value) {
            //alert('change occurred');
        }
    }, "rangeSlider");
```

You can find more detail here.

http://jsfiddle.net/g78Uk/21/